# Table headers fixed

Tags: css

I've read a lot of questions here answering my question but none of the code that I've found works in the current platform I'm working.

I need table headers fixed and a scroll to the table body.

Code of the table:

```
            <table id="mtable">

            <tr class="tamanhos">
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                {{each sizes}}
                ${endMark($data, sizes, ',')}
                <td style="text-align:left;">${$value.tam}</td>
                {{/each}}
            </tr>


            <div class="tbody">
            {{each colours}}
            <tr>
                ${endMark($data, colours, ',')}
                <td>${$value.cor} <input type="hidden" id="cor" name="corEscolhida[]" value="${$value.cor}" /></td>
                <td><span style="text-transform:none;">${$value.webtext}</span></td>
                {{each sizes}}
                <td class="bloco" style="text-align:left;">
                <input type="hidden" id="tam" name="tamEscolhido[]" value="${$value.tam}" />
                <input class="inserirQtd" style="max-width:30px;height:9px;font-size:11px;" id="quatd" name="quantidadeEscolhida[]" autocomplete="off" type="text" placeholder=""></input>
                <span width="40px" class="stockValor" name="stockValor"></span>
                <br><span class="stockValor2" style="font-size:10px;text-transform:none;" name="stockValor2"></span>
                </td>       
                {{/each}}
            </tr>
            {{/each}}


            <tr>
                <td colspan="100"><span id="webextra" style="float:left;text-transform:none;">${webextra}</span></td>
            </tr>
            </div>
        </table>
```

CSS of the table:

```
#mtable {
    border-collapse:none;
    border-spacing:none;
    margin:none;
}


#mtable>.tamanhos {
    display:block;
    height:25px;
}

#mtable>.tbody {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing a little Google couldn't fix.  Here is a pure CSS version, credit to a Jonas Schubert:

https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/light/

```
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #500;
}
section.positioned {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width:800px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #333;
}
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%;
}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  background: #ddd;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid #800;
}
th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: tried doesn't work. It makes my table all 'unformated'. I even checked the results of my search on google's page 2...

Comment: well, as you can see from the fiddle it works, you would need to take the example and integrate it in to what you have now, and remove anything that conflicts.. or make slight changes to accommodate your desired style.